# What to do when autofilter in VBA returns no data?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to filter a range of values and based on my criteria, at times I might have no data that fits my criteria. In that case, I do not want to copy any data from the filtered data. If there is filtered data, then I would like to copy it.

Here is my code:

```
With Workbooks(KGRReport).Worksheets(spreadSheetName).Range("A1:I" & lastrowinSpreadSheet)
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=LimitCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues 'Do the filtering for Limit
     .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=UtilizationCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues 'Do the filtering for Bank/NonBank
End With

'Clear the template
 Workbooks(mainwb).Worksheets("Template").Activate
 Workbooks(mainwb).Worksheets("Template").Rows(7 & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete

 'Copy the filtered data
 Workbooks(KGRReport).Activate
 Set myRange = Workbooks(KGRReport).Worksheets(spreadSheetName).Range("B2:H" & lastrowinSpreadSheet).SpecialCells(xlVisible)
 For Each myArea In myRange.Areas
     For Each rw In myArea.Rows
           strFltrdRng = strFltrdRng & rw.Address & ","
     Next
 Next

 strFltrdRng = Left(strFltrdRng, Len(strFltrdRng) - 1)
 Set myFltrdRange = Range(strFltrdRng)
 myFltrdRange.Copy
 strFltrdRng = ""
```

It is giving me an error at

```
Set myRange = Workbooks(KGRReport).Worksheets(spreadSheetName).Range("B2:H" & lastrowinSpreadSheet).SpecialCells(xlVisible)
```

When there is no data at all, it is returning an error: "No cells found".

Tried error handling like this post: [1004 Error: No cells were found, easy solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25380886/1004-error-no-cells-were-found-easy-solution)

But it was not helping. Need some guidance on how to solve this.

Comment: Just use something like: `If Workbooks(KGRReport).Worksheets(spreadSheetName).Range("B2:H" & lastrowinSpreadSheet).RowHeight Then` if nothing is shown, the height is `0` which will count as `False` (everything else will count as `True`)

Comment: FWIW the linked question (and the link from that question since it was a dupe) should have provided a viable path out of this issue.  That is, you need to handle the error if you know there is a chance it will be thrown.  I give an approach to avoid the error handling but the other answers essentially say the same as that other question: handle the error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try error handling like so:

```
Dim myRange As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set myRange = Range("your range here").SpecialCells(xlVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If myRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "no cells"
Else
    'do stuff
End If
```

Comment: where is the jump statement 0? where should it be written?

Comment: It isn't a jump statement, it clears the error handler.

Answer (score 2):

**An approach without the error handling**

It is possible to build the `AutoFilter` in a way that does not throw the error if nothing is found.  The trick is to **include the header row in the call to the `SpecialCells`**.  This will ensure that at least 1 row is visible even if nothing is found (Excel will not hide the header row).  This prevents the error from jamming up execution and gives you a set of cells to check if data was found.

To check if the resulting range has data, you need to check `Rows.Count > 1 Or Areas.Count > 1`.  This handles the two possible cases where your data is found directly under the header or in a discontinuous range below the header row.  Either result means that the `AutoFilter` found valid rows.

Once you check that data was found, you can then do the desired call to `SpecialCells` on the data only without concern for an error.

**Sample data [column C (field 2) will be filtered]:**

[image: random data]

```
Sub TestAutoFilter()

    'this is your block of data with headers
    Dim rngDataAndHeader As Range
    Set rngDataAndHeader = Range("B2").CurrentRegion

    'this will knock off the header row if you want data only
    Dim rngData As Range
    Set rngData = Intersect(rngDataAndHeader, rngDataAndHeader.Offset(1))

    'autofilter
    rngDataAndHeader.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=64

    'get the visible cells INCLUDING the header row
    Dim rngVisible As Range
    Set rngVisible = rngDataAndHeader.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    'check if there are more than 1 rows or if there are multiple areas (discontinuous range)
    If rngVisible.Rows.Count > 1 Or rngVisible.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        Debug.Print "found data"

        'data is available, this call cannot throw an error now
        Set rngVisible = rngData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        'do your normal execution here
        '
        '
        '
    Else
        Debug.Print "only header, no data included"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Result with Criteria1:=64**

`Immediate window: found data`

[image]

**Result with Criteria1:=0**

`Immediate window: only header, no data included`

[image]

**Other notes:**

- Code includes a separate variable called `rngData` if you want access to data without headers.  This is just an INTERSECT-OFFSET to bump it one row down.
- For the case where a result was found, code resets `rngVisible` to be the visible cells in the data only (skips header).  Since this call cannot fail now, it is safe without error handling.  This gives you a range that matches what you tried the first time but without the chance of getting an erorr.  This is not required if you can process the original range `rngVisible` that includes the headers.  If that is true, you can do away with `rngData` completely (unless you have some other need for it).

Answer (score 1):

since you use `myRange` as the real output of the filtering action you could go like follows

```
Dim wbKGRR As Workbook  '<== better set variable for workbooks you'll work with: it saves both typing time and possible errors
Dim ws As Worksheet  '<== better set variable for worksheets you'll work with: it saves both typing time and possible errors

'...


Set wbKGRR = Workbooks(KGRReport) '<== better set variable for workbooks: it saves both typing time and possible errors
Set ws = wbKGRR.Worksheets(spreadSheetName)  '<== better set variable for worksheets you'll work with: it saves both typing time and possible errors

With ws
    With .Range("A1:I" & lastrowinSpreadSheet)
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=LimitCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues 'Do the filtering for Limit
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=UtilizationCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues 'Do the filtering for Bank/NonBank
    End With
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns("B")) > 0 Then Set myRange = .Range("B2:H" & lastrowinSpreadSheet).SpecialCells(xlVisible) '<== myRange will be set only if filtering has left some visible cells
End With


'Clear the template
'Workbooks(mainwb).Worksheets("Template").Activate '<== no need to activate
Workbooks(mainwb).Worksheets("Template").Rows(7 & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete

'Copy the filtered data
' Workbooks(KGRReport).Activate '<== no need to activate
If Not myRange Is Nothing Then '<== "myRange" has been set properly if previous Autofilter method has left some visbile cells
    For Each myArea In myRange.Areas
        For Each rw In myArea.Rows
              strFltrdRng = strFltrdRng & rw.Address & ","
        Next rw
    Next myArea

    strFltrdRng = Left(strFltrdRng, Len(strFltrdRng) - 1)
    Set myFltrdRange = Range(strFltrdRng)
    myFltrdRange.Copy
    strFltrdRng = ""
End If
```

where I also suggested some workbook and worksheet variable settings to "ease" coding life

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code blow into a function.

```
Set myRange = Workbooks(KGRReport).Worksheets(spreadSheetName).Range("B2:H" & lastrowinSpreadSheet).SpecialCells(xlVisible)
```

In the function, use on error goto xxxx.
When error return nothing from the function and use "if myRange is not nothing then" to ignore the error cells.

Comment: This would be clearer if it included a code sample to produce the behavior you're describing.  I believe it will work, but it may not be obvious how to implement the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the responses below worked for me. Here is what I finally found that worked:

```
Sub fileterissues()

Dim VisibleRows as Long

‘Some code here

With Sheets(ws1).Range(“myrange”)
.Autofilter Field:=myfieldcolumn, criteria:=myfiltercriteria
VisibleRows = Application.Worksheetfunction.Subtotal(103, sheets(1).mycolumnfieldrange)
If VisibleRows = 0 then Resume Next
End with

‘More code

End sub
```