# VBA to stop macro with msg box if no criteria found in auto filter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to filter 2 different criteria which is "0" and "1" but I need a msg box pop out and stop the macro if there is no criteria found in the auto filter.

Can you advice how I can do that for below coding?

Thanks.

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$A$8").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=0", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=1"
Range("A3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Does it throw any kind of error if the filter doesn't exist. I guess there was one.

Comment: no, no error as it will filter nothing. I just hope it will stop and not run the coding for copy and paste to another row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562549/what-to-do-when-autofilter-in-vba-returns-no-data

Comment: You could just use `Application.CountIf` to test if there are any zeros or ones before filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should warn you if your filter returns no results. Note that I also had it turn off the filter at the end because some of the results (from C3 and below) could be hidden by the filter.

```
Sub CheckFilter()

    ''Remove any existing filters
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    With Range("A1")

        ''get range before filter
        Dim rngBefore As Range
        Set rngBefore = Range(.offset(1, 0), .offset(1, 0).End(xlDown))

        ''filter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=1"

        ''get range after filter
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim rngAfter As Range
        Set rngAfter = rngBefore.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0

        ''check whether any cells matching criteria were found
        If rngAfter Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No cells match filter"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            rngAfter.Copy Range("C3")
        End If

    End With

    ''Remove filter
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```