# Loop causing heavy CPU usage

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm pretty new to VBA and have (what I thought was) a pretty nifty little piece of code I wrote. It does exactly what I want it to (VLOOKUP based on the first letter in column F), but in the process, it throttles my computer's CPU (a 2.6GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7 that can do pretty heavy video editing). The macro isn't that complex and my dataset isn't big by most standards, I really don't think it should cause this to happen if I had the code running efficiently. Any ideas of what part of this loop is causing it or how to remedy the situation would be much appreciated-I imagine it's just some silly thing I'm missing being relatively new to looping. Thanks :)

```
         Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = .Range("F:F")
        Dim k As Long
        For k = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
                    If Left(rng.Item(k).Value, 1) = "U" Then
                        rng.Item(k).EntireRow.Delete
                    ElseIf Left(rng.Item(k).Value, 1) = "W" Then
                        With rng.Item(k)
                            .Activate
                            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G:G,WM!A:B,2,0), """")"
                            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G:G,WM!A:C,3,0), """")"
                            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G:G,WM!A:D,4,0), """")"
                        End With  
                    ElseIf Left(rng.Item(k).Value, 1) = "L" Then
                        With rng.Item(k)
                            .Activate
                            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G:G,LOWES!A:B,2,0), """")"
                            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G:G,LOWES!A:C,3,0), """")"
                        End With
        End If
        Next k
```

Comment: First thing is you are looping through 1 million rows. Limit your loop to the relevant range.

Comment: Avoid using `Activate`, `Select! `Limit the iteration to the last row of F:F. Comment `Activate' and use `.Offset(0, 3).Formula...` instead of `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Formula...` Use also `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` after iteration.

Comment: Second: you could avoid the loop altogether and just filter for your target cells with ` `Criteria1: = "=U*"` and then drop the formula in the resultant range all at once

Comment: @urdearboy indeed! just that F:F range was the culprit-throwing a constraint on there sped it right up. I'll have to use that Criteria in the future, I hadn't seen that function before--definitely a smoother process than a loop.

Comment: @FaneDuru I've been trying to wean myself off those horrible select/activate habits, thanks for the suggestions-I sometimes relapse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining my comments from above, you could do something like this to limit the range you are working with via a last row variable (`lr`) and using `AutoFilter` with wildcard (`*`) matching to avoid your loop altogether.

I removed your formulas for testing purposes on my end so just sub those back in and you should be good to go

---

```
Sub shelter_in_place()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")  '<-- UPDATE
Dim lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Handle "U*****"
ws.Range("F1:F" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=U*"
    ws.Range("F2:F" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
        ws.Cells.AutoFilter

'Handle "L****"
ws.Range("F1:F" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="L*"
    ws.Range("I2:I" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=1+1"
    ws.Range("J2:J" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=2+2"
    ws.Range("K2:K" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=3+3"
        ws.Cells.AutoFilter

'Handle "W****"
ws.Range("F1:F" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="W*"
    ws.Range("I2:I" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=4+4"
    ws.Range("J2:J" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=5+5"
        ws.Cells.AutoFilter


End Sub
```

---

*Notice there is no reliance of `Selection`, `Active`, `Select` etc. here. These are just middle operators and only act to slow your code down*

Comment: You will prob need to make some adjustments here to handle the chance that your filter returns no rows. The code right now assumes every time you run the code, the values to be filtered are present.

Comment: Here is a [good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36563207/6706419) to help you handle the case the filter returns NO rows

Comment: Shelter in Place handled all my problems, constraining the range still caused the CPU to ramp up to 29% (way more than excel generally uses). Using the Criteria/Autofilter method it doesn't get it above 10%-definitely the way to go if you're like me and cringe when the fans kick in. Thanks so much